# Creating a simple bicycle pedal motion

Tags: animation, armature, bones, constraints

I am trying out the various bone constraints in Blender. To further my understanding I am attempting to create the motion of a leg following the pedal of a bicycle. Please refer the image of the simple setup I am attempting.

[image: bone setup]

I have parented the 'Pedal' to the 'Disc' and have animated a rotation of the 'Disc' in the direction of the Blue arrow.

I am now trying to make the 'Feet' (oops! must be 'Foot') bone to follow the path of the 'Pedal' with an offset. I believe that after achieving this, adding an IK constraint to the 'Feet' bone and affecting all the way to 'Thigh' will give me the necessary motion. However, I am unable to achieve this. I am using Blender 2.7 on Linux.

Attempting to 'Copy Location' constraint on the 'Feet' object while specifying the target as 'Pedal' does not work.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but the calf needs to be at least as long as the thigh.

Comment: Hi Vince, Your point is valid. It seems to work for a few different ratios, but to look natural the lengths need to be similar if not identical.

Comment: Yes they do, and forgive me if I'm wrong, but the thigh seems to stretch diagonally across 2 BU while the calf doesn't look like it can even spen 2BU traight on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the bone is connected to its parent which constraint its location also leaving it parented will create some problems when using it as IK terget :

- in edit mode select the last bone and remove parent and clear connected

[image]

you can use the copy location constraint on the bone now and set it as IK target

[image]