# Anyway to rig this wheel?

Tags: rigging

trying to rig this robot, but I've got no idea how to do the wheel, any idea?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps consider separating and using it as a separate mesh?

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: Related or even a duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28120/creating-a-simple-bicycle-pedal-motion

Comment: that question is about the foot turning with the wheel, i do not even know how to let the wheel turn

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, is the wheel mesh part of the same object as the character?
You need to separate it by selecting all the faces and press "P"

You can turn the wheel into a rigid body constraint of the type: motor

here is a youtube tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lU9PADYJLM0

or you can skip that step and simply keyframe the rotation on it
here is a youtube tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFFhgutjZQk

And finally you need to use the graph editor to edit how your keyframes get interpolated
here is a youtube tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9gCHhJOjlQ

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Is it possible you could add a short summary of the content in the videos you linked? We like answers to be able to stand on their own in case the linked content becomes unavailable sometime in the future. Thanks

Comment: the first one is on rigid body constraints type:motor, the second one is on keyframes, and the third one is on the graph editor.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question more fully, I switched from comments to an answer.

The first thing I did was created and rigged a very rough estimate of your model:

[image]

I then added a square-ish wheel underneath it (visible in above picture). I parented this wheel to the armature via *Object (Keep Transform)*, not any of the *Armature Deform* settings. This means that when you move the armature, the wheel will move with it (assuming the transformation is in object mode). While the wheel moves in conjunction with the rest of the model, you are free to rotate it on the appropriate axis. Here is what I achieved (glitch is in gif alone):

[image]

Comment: Eh, how did you make it so the armature moves with the  estimate of my model?

Comment: I keyframed it while in object mode by pressing I and then selecting location.